# Awk string matching not working

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I am doing a pattern matching from two different files however the patterns do not seem to match even though I could identify certain values that were exact matches.
For instance:

```
awk '("BC036500-4"==$1) && ($18>0.8) {print "'"$line"'"" "$12":"$13"-"$14";"$15"*"$18}' xyz.txt
```

when xyz.txt does contain a row with the first column as BC036500-4. What could be the reason for pattern not working? 
I am running this in OS X terminal.

Comment: What's the value of `$line` ?

Comment: What's the value of field 18 on the line with `BC036500-4` as the first field?

Comment: Just guessing what your file looks like, the pattern matching works for me. But I'm probably guessing wrong. Why not give a few lines as an example, too?

Comment: My crystal ball says the fields in your input file aren't separated by chains of white space (e.g. maybe it's a CSV file? Or tab separated with empty fields? or something else?), but I must confess it's not always right. Post sample input and expected output, of course. And do NOT let shell variables expand into the body of awk scripts. Use `-v line="$line"` instead. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.